# Insert values associated to occurrences of column value using 2 Pandas DF's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have two df's

```
df1
col_1  col_2    col_3
  1     a1     "text1"
  2     a2     "text2"
  3     a1     "text3"
  4     a1     "text4"
```

```
df2
col_1  col_2
  1     a1     
  2     a2     
  3     a3
```

df1 has multiple occurrences of a value (student) in col_2, while df2 has only one occurrence. I am interested in the text in col_3 of df1.

I need to insert the text column of df1 into df2, handling for multiple occurrences of col_2.
The end result should be something like:

```
final_df

col_1   col_2        text_from_df1
  1        a1    ["text1,"text3","text4"]
  2        a2          ["text2"]
  3        a3             NaN
```

Any ideas? I am a bit stumped here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` on `df1` and then `right` `merge` them based on their specific columns `col_2`:

```
df_final = pd.merge(df1.groupby('col_2')['col_3'].apply(list), df2, left_on=['col_2'], right_on = ['col_2'], how = 'right')
```

output:

```
  col_2                  col_3  col_1
0    a1  [text1, text3, text4]      1
1    a2                [text2]      2
2    a3                    NaN      3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df2.merge(df1.groupby('col_2')['col_3'].apply(list).rename('text_from_df1').reset_index(), how='left')

   col_1 col_2                text_from_df1
0      1    a1  ["text1", "text3", "text4"]
1      2    a2                    ["text2"]
2      3    a3                          NaN
```

It would not be advisable for you to keep a `list` type object in pandas as it can lead to complications down the road.